# Inconsistent results with normalisation in dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr

I am trying to normalise a column ROE with this normalisation function

```
2*((PATORBIS$ROE-min(PATORBIS$ROE,na.rm = T))/
((max(PATORBIS$ROE,na.rm = T)-min(PATORBIS$ROE,na.rm = T))))-1
```

when I run the function above it gives me the correct normalisation, whereas using it with mutate from dplyr, the exact same function gives incorrect results.

Sample data:

```
PATORBIS <- data.frame(Company=c("ACHAOGEN","ACHAOGEN","ACHAOGEN","ACHAOGEN"),year=as.numeric(c("2013","2014","2015","2016")),ROE=as.numeric(c("-170","-31.2","-62.8",NA)))



plot2 <- PATORBIS %>% 
  select("Company","year","ROE") %>% 
  filter(!is.na(ROE)) %>% 
  mutate(ROE=2*(ROE-min(ROE,na.rm = T))/(max(ROE,na.rm = T)-min(ROE,na.rm = T))-1)
```

Does anyone have a similar issue of inconsistent results with mutate in dplyr?

Comment: Perhaps check whether you have loaded also `plyr`.  In that case specify `%>% dplyr::mutate(..`

Comment: the arent the same. one has round, the other doesnt?

Comment: can you also include a sample of your data to make this reproducible? If you could inlcude the inconsistent outcome as well that would make it much easier for us to help

Answer (score 0):

I got the same results, exactly the same removing the filter (and the select is not necessary)

```
library(dplyr)

PATORBIS <- data.frame(Company=c("ACHAOGEN","ACHAOGEN","ACHAOGEN","ACHAOGEN"),year=as.numeric(c("2013","2014","2015","2016")),ROE=as.numeric(c("-170","-31.2","-62.8",NA)))


plot2 <- PATORBIS %>% 
#  select("Company","year","ROE") %>% 
#  filter(!is.na(ROE)) %>% 
  mutate(ROE=2*(ROE-min(ROE,na.rm = T))/(max(ROE,na.rm = T)-min(ROE,na.rm = T))-1)

plot2

2*((PATORBIS$ROE-min(PATORBIS$ROE,na.rm = T))/
     ((max(PATORBIS$ROE,na.rm = T)-min(PATORBIS$ROE,na.rm = T))))-1
```